# Application crashes displaying a GroundOverlay made with a Canvas in Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-canvas, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm displaying a GroundOverlay on my map whose image is made with a canvas on which I drew an arc, but I'm running into a few problems : first of all, the applications crashes after a little while (it's giving me a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError), and it's not showing the overlay. I have tried putting on a white background in the overlay's picture and it does display it, so I guess the problem comes from the arc, but I can't tell what I did wrong. Anyone has any idea ?

```
Projection projection = map.getProjection();

                    Point point1 = projection.toScreenLocation(latlng1);
                    Point point2 = projection.toScreenLocation(latlng2);

                    float startAngle = (float) (Math.atan2(point1.y - point2.y,
                            point1.x - point2.x));
                    float sweepAngle = (float) (GenericNdData.getLateralTrajectory(
                            T_FplnType.ACTIVE.getId()).getSegment(i).getAngle());

                    float radius = FloatMath.sqrt((float) (Math.pow(
                            (point1.x - point2.x), 2) + Math.pow(
                            (point1.y - point2.y), 2)));
                    RectF rectangle = new RectF(point2.x - radius, point2.y
                            - radius, point2.x + radius, point2.y + radius);

                    Paint paint = new Paint();

                    paint.setARGB(250, 0, 255, 0);
                    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
                    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
                    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                    paint.setStrokeWidth(4f * Configuration.General.getScreenFactor());

                    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

                    Bitmap arc = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(arc);
                    canvas.drawColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                    canvas.drawArc(rectangle,
                            (float) (Math.toDegrees(startAngle)),
                            (float) (Math.toDegrees(sweepAngle)), false, paint);

                    GroundOverlay groundArc = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
                     .image(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(arc))
                     .position(latlng2, 10000));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you have this code called?

Comment: In a Fragment that displays the map (not a MapFragment, one I made myself)

Comment: In onResume or something like this? I'd like to know if this code is called multiple times by accident.

Comment: Oh, and in a function which is called every time there is an update (my application displays information taken from another program). Basically each time a modification has been made on the other application, that function is called again, and the arc changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known memory leak issue related to `BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap()` when used with Markers. It might be an issue here, but first try to:

```
GroundOverlay.remove()
```

previously added object before calling `GoogleMap.addGroundOverlay`.

Comment: I just added this and it appears to be working, thank you ! However, I still have a problem with the arc not being displayed.

Comment: Maybe an issue with stroke width value? Try hardcoding 100 as the width.

Comment: OK, I was able to solve that myself : you need to replace "RectF rectangle = new RectF(point2.x - radius, point2.y - radius, point2.x + radius, point2.y + radius);" by : "RectF rectangle = new RectF(0, 0, radius*2, radius*2);" (with the previous line, the arc is drawn at the screen location corresponding to the latlng coordinates, but since we're using a canvas, we must draw the arc at the (0,0) coordinates)