# Calculate latitude longitude for added height

Tags: android, gps, latitude-longitude

I want to draw a line chart on the Android google map.
I have gps coordinates of the path and I want to show the speed of the car on the map with the height of the line.

See this image Something like this,

[image]

For each gps (lat,lng) point I want to add some height and calculate the corresponding gps(lat,lng) point. I want to show this in a 3D view so I will have to change the points when the camera position is changed but first step is to calculate the gps points with the added height.

For example

```
ArrayList<LatLng> basePoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262688, -2.500792));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262758, -2.500897));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262789, -2.501087));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262798, -2.501229));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262785, -2.501414));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262760, -2.501594));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262707, -2.501811));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262655, -2.501943));

ArrayList<LatLng> topPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.262939, -2.500779));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.262975, -2.500916));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.262914, -2.501098));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.263055, -2.501248));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.262925, -2.501439));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.263045, -2.501581));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.262907, -2.501844));
topPoints.add(new LatLng(53.263002, -2.502015));
```

Any idea how can I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20407310/groundoverlay-made-with-a-canvas-in-google-maps-android-api-v2/20409227#20409227) you provided I have implemented this for you.

```
final ArrayList<LatLng> basePoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262688, -2.500792));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262758, -2.500897));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262789, -2.501087));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262798, -2.501229));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262785, -2.501414));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262760, -2.501594));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262707, -2.501811));
basePoints.add(new LatLng(53.262655, -2.501943));

final ArrayList<Double> speedPoints = new ArrayList<Double>();
speedPoints.add(7.955734692);
speedPoints.add(8.761378798);
speedPoints.add(11.07760474);
speedPoints.add(13.69594751);
speedPoints.add(15.50864695);
speedPoints.add(16.01217576);
speedPoints.add(15.60935179);
speedPoints.add(15.71005663);

LatLngBounds.Builder bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for(int i=0;i<basePoints.size();i++)
{
    bounds.include(basePoints.get(i));
}
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds.build(), 300,300,0));
map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0)
    {
        map.clear();
        ArrayList<LatLng> topPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        for(int i=0;i<basePoints.size();i++)
        {
            topPoints.add(moveByDistance(basePoints.get(i), speedPoints.get(i)*3,map.getCameraPosition().bearing));
        }
        PolylineOptions topPO = new PolylineOptions();
        topPO.addAll(topPoints).width(5).color(Color.BLUE).geodesic(true);
        map.addPolyline(topPO);
        for(int i=0;i<basePoints.size()-1;i++)
        {
            map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().add(basePoints.get(i),topPoints.get(i),topPoints.get(i+1),basePoints.get(i+1),basePoints.get(i)).fillColor(Color.YELLOW).strokeColor(Color.YELLOW));
        }
    }

});

/**
 * Move a LatLng-Point into a given distance and a given angle (0-360,
 * 0=North).
 */
public static LatLng moveByDistance(LatLng startGp, double distance,double angle) {
    /*
     * Calculate the part going to north and the part going to east.
     */
    double arc = Math.toRadians(angle);
    double toNorth = distance * Math.cos(arc);
    double toEast = distance * Math.sin(arc);
    double lonDiff = meterToLongitude(toEast, startGp.latitude);
    double latDiff = meterToLatitude(toNorth);
    return new LatLng(startGp.latitude + latDiff, startGp.longitude + lonDiff);
}

private static double meterToLongitude(double meterToEast, double latitude) {
    double latArc = Math.toRadians(latitude);
    double radius = Math.cos(latArc) * EARTHRADIUS;
    double rad = meterToEast / radius;
    double degrees = Math.toDegrees(rad);
    return degrees;
}

private static double meterToLatitude(double meterToNorth) {
    double rad = meterToNorth / EARTHRADIUS;
    double degrees = Math.toDegrees(rad);
    return degrees;
}
```

I hope it will help you implement this.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to do, I did not think it would be that easy. CameraChangeListener is to easy to implement. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Calcualte how many degrees one meter is:

At equator:

360 degrees, 
have 40.000 000 meters circumfene.

So one meter is about

```
double static final METERS_PER_DEGREE = 360.0 / 40 000 000;
```

Now offset the latitude e.g by 3 meters:

```
lat = lat + 3 * METERS_PER_DEGREE.
```

When offseting longitude, one has to multiply with `cos(Math.toRadians(latitude);`

```
double oneMeterLongitudeInDegrees = METERS_PER_DEGREE * cos(Math.toRadians(latitude);

lonNew = lonOld + 3 * oneMeterLongitudeInDegrees
```

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20409227/1384302) answer which seems to be working well